# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error is given even though I granted Select privilege to the user

Tags: oracle

For my Oracle database I created a user. I want that user to have access to only 3 tables. So I wrote those queries:

```
grant select on table1 to newuser;
grant select on table2 to newuser;
grant select on table3 to newuser;
```

And I got this from the console, which ensures that I gave the grant.

```
GRANT succeeded
```

However when I connect to database with this user and write the following query, I get ORA-00942 error.

```
Select * from table1;
```

I think I need to write additional queries for privileges and roles(I already added CONNECT role). What might it be?

Comment: You need GRANT CREATE SESSION

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the query by specifying table owner.

```
Select * from tableowner.table1;
```

If this doesn't work then either you have not granted access on correct table or you are logged in with wrong user.

remember same table name can exist in multiple schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that,

- **NEWUSER** --> THE user to which a grant has been provided.
- **EXISTINGUSER**  --> The owner of the table for which a grant is provided.

Login as **EXISTINGUSER**, and enter following query:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE1 TO NEWUSER ;
```

Login as **NEWUSER**, and select using:

```
SELECT * FROM EXISTINGUSER.TABLE1;
```

In case you want to avoid using "EXISTINGUSER"."TABLE1", then you can create a [synonym](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php), which is equivalent to a **ALIAS NAME**:

Login as **NEWUSER**, enter following query:

```
CREATE SYNONYM SYN_TABLE1 FOR EXISTINGUSER.TABLE1;
```

For selecting data from synonym, login as **NEWUSER** and select using:

```
SELECT * FROM SYN_TABLE1;
```

Synonym Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm